# Верстка, отобразить объекты в блоки, или в ленту

Tags: вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не знаю как сделать кнопку при которой можно было бы сменить вид объектов как на скриншоте, html/css/js

Comment: на кнопки вещайте обработчик и в зависимости от обработчика вешаете класс, а этим классом управляете грид системой

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```js
const el1 = document.getElementById("rows");
const el2 = document.getElementById("columns");
const mainLayaout = document.getElementById("mainLayaout");
el1.addEventListener("click", toRows, false);
el2.addEventListener("click", toColumns, false);

function toRows() {
  mainLayaout.style.cssText = "display: flex; flex-direction: column"; 
}

function toColumns() {
  mainLayaout.style.cssText = "display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)"; 
}
```

```css
#card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button id="rows">Список</button>
<button id="columns">Колонки</button>
<div id="mainLayaout">
  <section id="card"></section>
  <section id="card"></section>
  <section id="card"></section>
</div>
```